# Parse element from redirected page with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, redirect, simple-html-dom, domparser

I'm trying to parse a title from redirected page. Here is my code:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$link="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+google";
$html = file_get_html($link);

foreach ($html->find('title') as $text){
    echo $text->plaintext."<br/>";

}
?>
```

The result should be "Google". Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"redirected page"_? And instead of just posting the code you have and what you want, you might want to let us know what your actual issue is? What happens when you run your code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My case is simple. I have an input field, which on submitting should be return a title from the first found page in duckduckgo search engine and the link for it.. For example: You submit in the input field "Stack Overflow", and the return should be: Title: Stack Overflow; url: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+stackverflow   
That's it. But now in my case, when I echo $text->plaintext, its showing a blank page. I hope You can understand me now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I 100% understood your request, but here are a few things to help you move on !

Three things :

1. the "!" in the $link redirects you to google. Delete it if you want to access the ducky result page.
2. simple-html-dom can't access the ducky result page. Did you try to echo the $html to see what you get ? I tried and was blocked by a captcha ... you'll need to figure out how to bypass it. Then and only then you'll have access to the titles.
3. Finally, your titles are H2 ... it might be easier to reach h2 tags with the parser.

Does this help ?
If you find a way to bypass the captcha let me know ! I'm interested :)

Answer (score 0):

After use Simle DOM find URL redirected page :

```
<?php 

$url="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+google";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL



echo $url; // your url hire *_*  AppsGM
?>
```

AND now use your code

```
    <?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach ($html->find('title') as $text){
    echo $text->plaintext."<br/>";

}
?>
```